# Como criar um espaçamento entre links da mesma célula de uma tabela?

Tags: php, html

A célula de minha tabela deve exibir o link de redirecionamento para `SELECT`, `UPDATE` e `DELETE` na mesma célula, porém fica tudo junto e eu queria saber como faz para criar um espaço entre os links.

- Saída esperada

```
SELECT UPDATE DELETE
```

- Atual saída

```
SELECTUPDATEDELETE
```

- Código

```
echo '<td>'."<a href='../crud/select_itens_compra.php'>SELECT</a>"."<a href='../crud/update_itens_compra.php'>UPDATE</a>"."<a href='../crud/delete_itens_compra.php'>DELETE</a>".'</td>';
```

Comment: Cara pq vc não usa CSS para resolver isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colocando um espaço na frente de cada  funciona, veja o código abaixo:

```
echo '<td>'."<a href='../crud/select_itens_compra.php'>SELECT</a> "."<a href='../crud/update_itens_compra.php'>UPDATE</a> "."<a href='../crud/delete_itens_compra.php'>DELETE</a>".'</td>';
```

Caso queira adicionar mais de um espaço, basta acrescentar `&nbsp`; para cada espaço que queira adicionar.

```
echo '<td>'."<a href='../crud/select_itens_compra.php'>SELECT</a>&nbsp;"."<a href='../crud/update_itens_compra.php'>UPDATE</a>&nbsp;"."<a href='../crud/delete_itens_compra.php'>DELETE</a>".'</td>';
```

Comment: Entendi, só agora percebi que o problema a solução era simples, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

```css
td{padding:0 15px;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>SELECT</td><td>UPDATE</td><td>DELETE</td></tr>
</table>
```